# Deploying a Play Framework application on port 80 beside Apache

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, playframework

I'm looking for a way to deploy my Play-Framework-1.0 application on the port 80.
So first I made the zip file with 'dist' command, then I unzipped it.
When I run the command to lauch the application (`play-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/play-java -Dhttp.port=80 -Dhttp.adresse=127.0.0.1`), I get this error :

```
[error] p.c.s.NettyServer - Failed to listen for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:80!
Oops, cannot start the server.
play.core.server.ServerListenException: Failed to listen for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:80!
at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$bindChannel(NettyServer.scala:215)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:203)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:203)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:203)
at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:266)
at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:265)
at play.core.server.ServerProvider$class.createServer(ServerProvider.scala:25)
at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:265)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:53)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

Moreover, in the real server, Apache has been installed. So I wonder, whether that will be a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Well if port 80 is not available, you will not be able to use it. Try port 8080

Comment: What do you really mean by 'beside Apache' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Linux server, you can try '`fuser 80/tcp`' to see whether another process is already running on that port (80). If so (there's showing a process-id, when you enter the command), you cannot use the same port for 2 processes.

Either, you have to start the Play-app in a different port or you can kill the already running process by '`sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`' and start the Play-app on the same port (80).

Answer (score 3):

Optionally, also remember that on most systems, running processes on ports lower than 8000 is disabled in default, in such case you need to allow it, i.e. on Unix servers, just using `sudo` command(prefix).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have two processes running on the same host listening on the same port.

However, you could run you Play application on different port, e.g. 8080 and set up Apache as a reverse proxy (Nginx would do too, but you mentioned that you already have Apache running on the server) to forward requests to your Play application.

Example guide how to do that: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension